# Typescript complex type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'd like to do a more detailed type inference for Rule3

```
export interface BaseOption {
  required?:true;
}

export type Validator = {
  [key in string]?: (
    val: number,
    formData: string,
    callback,
    props
  ) => void | Promise<void | Error>;
};

export interface RequiredFunc {
  required: (message: string) => void;
}

export type CombineOptions<ExtraOption extends Validator> = ExtraOption &
  RequiredFunc;

function Rule<ExtraOption extends Validator>(
  options: ExtraOption | BaseOption
) {
  return {} as ExtraOption extends BaseOption
    ? CombineOptions<ExtraOption>
    : ExtraOption;
}

// Condition1
const rule1 = Rule({
  a() {},
});

rule1.a; // There are code hints in vscode

// Condition2
const rule2 = Rule({ required: true });

rule2.required; // There are code hints in vscode

// Condition3
const rule3 = Rule({
  a(f, b) {},
  required: true,
});

rule3.required; // There are code hints in vscode
rule3.a; // There are no code hints in vscode
```

How do I get the code hint for a in condition 3.If I do not add generics manually, the  condition 3 is not worked in vscode. Is my type inference the wrong way?

Comment: Works for me in the typescript playground, maybe your vscode version of typescript is old or something?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL492m) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz You're right. You've done me a great favor

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum The issue  has been solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking if you want the compiler to infer a type parameter `X`, you should give it a value of type `X` from which to infer it.  In your `Rule` function you were trying to infer `X extends Validator` from an `options` value of type `X | BaseOption`, and the results were not great.  As soon as `options` was assignable to `BaseOption`, the compiler gave up with inferring `X` more specifically and it fell back to `Validator`, causing both `rule2` and `rule3` to be of type `CombineOptions<Validator>`, which is true but not specific enough for your needs.

If we refactor so that `X` is itself a type that extends `Validator | BaseOption` and that `options` is of type `X`, then inference will work correctly and the compiler will not forget the specific properties of `options`:

```
function Rule<X extends Validator | BaseOption>(options: X): RuleOutput<X> {
    return {} as any // impl
}
```

The issue now is to figure out how to express the output type `RuleOutput<X>` as a function of the input type `X`.  From reading your `RequiredFunc` and `CombineOptions` types, it looks like what you want to do is output `X` more or less as-is, except if there is a key named `required`, you want to change that property type to be `(message: string) => void`.  That can be expressed via a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with a [conditoinal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to check for the condition where the key is `required`:

```
type RuleOutput<X> = {
    [K in keyof X]:
    K extends "required" ? (message: string) => void : X[K]
}
```

---

Let's see if it works:

```
// Condition1
const rule1 = Rule({
    a() { },
});
/* const rule1: {
    a: () => void;
} */

// Condition2
const rule2 = Rule({ required: true });
/* const rule2: {
    required: (message: string) => void;
} */
    
// Condition3
const rule3 = Rule({
    a(f, b) { },
    required: true,
});
/* const rule3: {
    a: (f: number, b: string) => void;
    required: (message: string) => void;
} */
```

Looks good.  Your `rule1` is the same type as before, and now `rule2` and `rule3` are more specific and know about the specific keys passed in as `options`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=0#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-5Cdyg8GQ6FwVJOWOteOJ5Oyegd9M9v4J2Q5g356gAZmLwatGw3FYdkbl7nQ4TgITdHtKTEXdeEomAXub-sDJd3wA3Xe80ZPAWCYSgM8QhhNI4QnZFJDFGsl37QcIShEDx2aScdGnFM52tDcF2g3hJDTLCs1nJBMEHMAcDwUg0kcUVmHkaB4GQVAMHIxkSHILkaMyW9-jcBsJCiGQojoxQllUOBqR0PQDCOKITiuC4xzhVx+1kso-E0P9QgiVTMliKAEiSRC4WvMomGyTRcnyWoSh06IKiqHkiiUWzwPjBk+ggAZhmRBlJmmWYBIWbxhIYlA0CwXAiRw-4ADFcWwTjom4nhYLBeCR0U+FkIggTZGC8B6OUMT9VCZBmS5IghnGEAREwdjWTJGqKXecStEkulDjgaravqwkADJbJWaKeDivEguYHE8Q4gUqpqqA6pZQlyUpVqaSkmZPFMzlWR5br5t6mhukINjFqQBpEqgiUpToWV5T2haOOWlrjvK1lbO8YESpCMqDsq+6Dqad7mCEf7Tsg5hBO8Vc8xNKI21LMMDw2R1bJdS9PQE5sodbN803DRK0aEHLollGdu2tY1M3EZVVQAFQACzQPBMFYV8eDwenGI+ZBWiIc12by5hRLwXVSDUO0vp+07Kok2loEBqJocNLki28eH33LYxK3dZL6wfJtwaYHV1Y7IRJaQV6LSGWX1sBsUy2w35cJpuAGaZuVWf5jmuYuHw+YgAXFdVXNldZLc1dxzCkeAFHTJdU9z3RkyoKdvt7zEEzvUNl2Tcws3PO+i3futtq5Zmcm90d3sExdt3WZZvAvbgTmUG5mg-a9iuPyp2vGfr1mkAgNnvdb33-cDwSgA)

Comment: I have another idea. I don't know if it'll work. Is there a way to infer the type more intelligently if I make the parameters of the Rule method optional?

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W484eW)

Comment: This seems out of scope for the question, but you'd need to give some default for `X` in that case... like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxBoKw) maybe.